# how to change the value of sp-navigate-reindent-after-up in smartparens

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, parentheses

I want to change the default behavior of [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) to remove the whitespace before the close delimiter. I mean, when I type `)` after `(a b c    |`, I hope the final result is `(a b c)|`. Here, the `|` is cursor.

I searched the [documentation of smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki), and find that sp-navigate-reindent-after-up may response to this behavior. However, I don't know how to change it.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In fact, when using smartparens in lisp-mode of Emacs, the parentheses is balanced. So when I type `(`, it give `(|)`, and then when I type `)`, it gives `()|`. The paredit package for Emacs will eat extra whitespace before `)`, so when type `)` after `(a b c    |)`, it will give `(a b c)`. My question is how to get the same results when using smartparens package.  That's the above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a smartparens user but I found the answer from its [wiki](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Paredit-and-smartparens#random-differences):

You can bind `)` to `sp-up-sexp` command:

```lisp
(define-key smartparens-mode-map ")" #'sp-up-sexp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer provides a hint to use `sp-up-sexp`, and I get the correct code to bind the command to `)` from  [this wiki page](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Working-with-expressions).